# How can I connect a signal QPushButton.clicked to differents function regarding a condition

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm programming a GUI interface which display parameters (from an xls input file) by using a QlistWidget. Under this list, I create a QPushButton to copy the selected item on the list to Xls Database. The function of this button, so far, is to copy whatever item which has been selected from the list. The piece of code displayed below realized this connection:

```
liste = List()
self.copy = QPushButton("Add Parameter  to Database")   
self.copy.clicked.connect(lambda: liste.copy_to_xls('Parameter_Name'))
```

The *copy_to_xls* method of the **List** Class (which is derived from the QlistWidget) that I created, handle the copy of the selected item from the list to the Database.

Everything is going well so far, but now, I would like to copy only some specified item by condition in the Database.

*For example*:

- If the selected item is named "Alpha", when I push the button, the item is copied on the database
- Otherwise, if the selected item is named "Gama", when I try to push button, a PopUp Window appear to inform me that is not possible.

I would like to have some tips to manage this solution, I think that I had to use some signals but I couldn't find the way to get it. How could I get different actions (either copy or popUp displayed) from the same event (clicked on the button).

Maybe, should I subclass QPushButton to create its own signal?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-You can DUPLICATE, the signal line the command that

```py
  self.YourButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.do_something1)
  self.YourButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.do_something2)
  self.YourButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.do_something3)
  self.YourButton.clicked.connect(self.call_a_Function_or_doAnythingElse)
  ...
```

2-Methode, would be to pass by an intermediate function that connect/initiat to different

```py
    self.YourButton.clicked.connect(self.Intermediate_Function)
def Intermediate_Function(self):
    self.do_something1
    self.do_something2
    self.do_something3
    self.do_something4
    ...
```